# Handle button event in UITableviewcell

Tags: iphone, ios, events, uitableview, uibutton

I am trying to get a number from an array and store it in a button in UITableview cell. When I tap the button,  I should be able to get the number. Whats the right way to get the information from the sender in the button click event

This is what I tried.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil )
{
    UIButton *button = [[[UIButton alloc]init]autorelease];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(180, 10, 33, 33);
    button.frame = frame;
    button.tag = 1001;

    UIImage *image = [[[UIImage alloc]init]autorelease];
    image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(onIconTapped)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [button setHidden:YES];
    cell.accessoryView = button;  

}

int myContactID = contact.contactID;
NSLog(@"My No.  %d", myContactID);
NSNumber *mySelectedNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:myContactID];

UIButton *myButton = (UIButton *)[cell.accessoryView viewWithTag:1001];
for(int i = 0; i< [myContactsArray count]; i++){
    if([[[myContactsArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"RecordID"] isEqualToNumber:mySelectedNumber]){

        [myButton setHidden:NO];
        NSString *myString;
        myString = [[myContactsArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"MYNumber"];
        [myButton setTitle:myString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        myButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:0];
        NSLog(@"my number %@", myString);
        NSLog(@"Button tag %@", myButton.currentTitle);
        break;
    }
    else{
       [myButton setHidden:YES];
    }
}
}



-(void)onIconTapped:(id)sender{
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)onIconTapped:(id)sender{

  if (sender.tag == 1001){
  NSString *title = sender.currentTitle;

  NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
  [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

  NSNumber *titleNumber = [numberFormatter numberFromString:title]; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Edit: -(void)onIconTapped:(id)sender{ UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;  if (button.tag == 1001){// do things}

Answer (score 2):

This approach is from iOS Recipes (Matt Drance): You can get the cell with converting the origin of the button to the tableView (`convertPoint:toView:`) and then call

```
[[self tableView] indexPathForRowAtPoint: convertedPoint];
```

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(onIconTapped:) `enter code here`forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

2.

```
myString = [[myContactsArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"MYNumber"];
button.tag = i;`
```

3.

```
-(void)onIconTapped:(id)sender{
Contact *contact = [myContactsArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag];

}
```